# Ternary inside string literals

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

Been trying to add a conditionals inside a template strings. I am unable to do it. I have two strings say t1 and t2, and when t2 is undefined or empty just display t1 and when t2 is present append that t2 inside parentheses along with t1

```
let t1= "hey";
let t2 = "there";
//need the output something like hey(there) when there t2 is present. when it is null or undefined or empty just show hey 

//Have tried the below but it is not working
console.log(`${t2} ${t1} ? ${t1}(${t2}): ${t1}`)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ternary should be done inside of the `${}` expression as follows:

```js
let t1 = "hey";
let t2 = "there";
console.log(`${t1}${t2 ? `(${t2})` : ''}`);
```

An explanation of the code above is as follows:

1. Since you've specified that the prefix "`hey`" should be specified regardless of whether you've defined `t2` or not, there's no need to include it in the ternary expression.
2. The next part of the code is an inlined ternary operator that checks if `t2` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

   - If it is truthy, the first part of the ternary operator is executed. In other words, the ternary operator will return `(${t2})`. And since this is another template literal, this will be evaluated with the substitution of the `t2` variable into the template expression.
   - If it isn't truthy, the second part of the ternary operator is executed, which is an empty string.

Note that you can have template literals inside template literals. See the [Template Literals documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Nesting_templates) on MDN for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just checking for the `falsy` value of your variable (null ,undefined, false, ...) you can use the below code:

```js
console.log(`${t2 ? `${t1}(${t2})` : `${t1}`}`)
```

This will check for the empty value of `t2`.

If you want to check for being defined of the variable, you can use this one:

```js
console.log(`${typeof t2 !== 'undefined' ? `${t1}(${t2})` : `${t1}`}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let t1= "hey";
let t2 = "there";

console.log(`${t1}${t2 ? `(${t2})` : ''}`)

t2 = null;

console.log(`${t1}${t2 ? `(${t2})` : ''}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Expression can only be written inside `{}` when using string literals. You need to use nested template strings here

```js
let t1= "hey";
let t2 = "there";
console.log(`${t1}${t2 ? `(${t2})` : ''}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

So in your code, what happened is, the ternary operators where also part of the string, try the below code.

```
let t1= "hey";
let t2 = "";

console.log(t2 ? `${t1}(${t2})` : t1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

```js
let t1= "hey";
let t2 = "there";
//need the output something like hey(there) when there t2 is present. when it is null or undefined or empty just show hey 

//Have tried the below but it is not working
console.log(t2 ? `${t1} (${t2})`: `(${t1})`)
console.log(`${t1} ${t2 && `(${t2})`}`)


t1= "hey";
t2 = "";

console.log(t2 ? `${t1} (${t2})`: `${t1}`)
console.log(`${t1} ${t2 && `(${t2})`}`)
```